# SpringBatch is blocking insertion of data in other tables

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

i am using Postgres as my SQL.My Springboot application uses Spring Batch for processing and insertion of data.I am auditing my code flow like say suppose one 3rd party api which i call if it fails i audit this failure event.This piece of code is in my Spring Batch Writer.I see logs of my AUDIT DTO class getting created however i dont see data in audit table.The same if i move code of auditing outside Spring Batch writer -it works.What should be done so that my audit table insertion code in Spring Batch writer works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details would be needed to be sure but I assume your writer writes to the 3rd party API and you write the audit log to the same `DataSource` that you use for the Spring Batch meta data.

Every write of a chunk that Spring Batch does in a writer is wrapped in a transaction. Such a transaction will be rolled back if you throw an exception in the writer.

You need to write the audit log outside of the transaction created by Spring Batch. For example by using Spring transaction management and starting a new transaction with propagation level `REQUIRES_NEW`.